# python email update content

Tags: python, html-email

I have a snippet of code, in for loop to send email updating the email content for each iteration in for loop. but the email body doesn't get update . please help me.

I've tried adding del message but no luck

```
for i in range(0,3) :
    data = [[i,i,i,i,i,]]+data
    print(data)
    text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
    html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))
    message = MIMEMultipart(
        "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])
    #message.attach(MIMEText(html,'html'))i
    sub_time = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(hours=5,minutes=30)
    sub = "Time - "+str(sub_time.hour)+":"+str(sub_time.second)

    message['Subject'] = sub
    message['From'] = me
    message['To'] = you
    server.login(me, password)

    server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
```

here in mail, I get 0,0,0,0,0+data for all 3 iterations.

Comment: whats the original data of `data`?

Comment: some list of list.. irrestpective of data (constant or varying ) , [[i,i,i,i,i]] should get update but its not happending

Comment: `for i in range(3):
    data = [[i,i,i,i,i,]]+data` seems to work for me. Is it that the email is sending the same thing or is it printing the same thing?

Comment: `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]` will always be present in all iterations because you are always adding `data` to its previous value. In other words, the `[[i, i, i, i]]` from a previous iteration will always be part of `data` in the next iteration after you do `+ data`. Try not re-using `data` but assign to a different variable `iter_data = [[i, i, i, i]] + data` if you do not wish for the data to pile over itself.

Comment: here problem isnt with data, i change it to data = [[i,i,i,i,i,i]]+[[0,0,0,0,0,0]], when i print i will get update to 0,1,2 accordly but in mail it doesnt appear. here the question is how to update the content of multipartmessage object.

Comment: what shows in the email? could you give us the exact text?

Comment: value of the first iteration i.e 0 0 0 0 0 0 \n
0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: that would be expected though...

Comment: sorry i dint get you, so in MIMEMultipart message body you cant update ?

Comment: no, you said in the first iteration, the contents were `0 0 0 0 0 0 \n 0 0 0 0 0 0`. That is expected as the first iteration of the loop outputs that.

Comment: Is the next iteration different?

Comment: no.. for all iteration i get the same output. i.,e 0 0 0 0 0 0 \n 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197800/discussion-between-axium-and-keerthan-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
##text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))

text = format(tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
##html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))

html = format(tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))
```